# how to call a value list with variables in for range | django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have difficulty in printing the list in sequence, I've done my best still :(

## tool/views.py

```
class aswq(FormView):
form_class = AswqForm
template_name = "tool/aswq.html"
context_object_name = "result"

def post(self,request):
    if request.method == "POST" or "post":
       self.query = request.POST['query']
       self.context = {
               'anime_title':[],
               'thumbnail':[],
               }
       self.results = AnimeSearchWithQuery.keyword(self.query)
       self.var = 0
       for self.result in range(0,len(self.results['title'])):
           self.context['anime_title'].append(self.results['title'][self.var])
           self.createdAt = self.results['createdAt'][self.var]
           self.updatedAt = self.results['updatedAt'][self.var]
           self.startDate = self.results['startDate'][self.var]
           self.endDate   = self.results['endDate'][self.var]
           self.nextRelease = self.results['nextRelease'][self.var]
           self.status    = self.results['status'][self.var]
           self.subtype   = self.results['subtype'][self.var]
           self.popularityR = self.results['popularityRank'][self.var]
           self.ratingR   = self.results['ratingRank'][self.var]
           self.favoritesC  = self.results['favoritesCount'][self.var]
           self.synopsis  = self.results['synopsis'][self.var]
           self.context['thumbnail'].append(self.results['thumbnail'][self.var])
           self.var += 1

    return render(request,'tool/result.html',{
                'results':self.context,
                "range":range(0,len(self.context['anime_title']))
                })
```

template, tool/result.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}
{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
{% for i in range %}
{{results.anime_title.i}}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

if it's in python it's like this

```
list = {'sub':['en','id'],'genre':     ['horror','games'],}
for i in range(0,len(list['sub'])):
      print('subtitle: {}'.format(list['sub'][i]))
      print('genre : {}'.format(list['genre'][i]))
```

can django do such a structure?, thanks if i can't explain / bad english

Comment: Can you please share the expected result and the current result?

Comment: And also the data stored in the anime title list

Comment: @ChetanVashisth the results I want to print sequentially and currently only display without output

Comment: @ChetanVashisth {'anime_title': ['Naruto', 'Naruto: Shippuden', 'The Last: Naruto the Movie', 'Road to Ninja: Naruto the Movie', 'Naruto: Shippuden the Movie', 'Boruto: Naruto Next Generations', 'Naruto x UT', 'Naruto: Shippuden the Movie 2 -Bonds-', 'Naruto the Movie 2: Legend of the Stone of Gelel', 'Boruto: Naruto the Movie'], 'thumbnail': ['https://media.kitsu.io/anime/poster_images/11/original.jpg?1417705323', 'https://media.kitsu.io/anime/poster_images/1555/original.jpg?1489946654', 'https://media.kitsu.io/anime/poster_images/7543/original.jpg?1416596467', 'https://media.kitsu.io/anime/p

Comment: @ChetanVashisth hi bro, is there any solution ? :v

Comment: I let you know when i get something for you bro